# Estrutura de Controller e View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Uma ajuda para não fazer algo muito mais trabalhoso do que pode ser logo de cara.
Possuo as seguintes classes na minha *Model*:

```
public Pessoa {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TipoPessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contato> Contatos { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Refencia> Referencias { get; set; }
    //...
} 

public Conjuge {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    //...
}

public Contato {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Anotacao { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    //...
}

public Referencia {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Anotacao { get; set; }
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

E a questão é a seguinte: Preciso montar minha view (single-page) da seguinte maneira:

- Campos de Pessoa
- Campos de Conjuge
- Pessoa pode ter N Contatos
- Form adicionar Contato para Pessoa
- Pessoa pode ter N Referências
- Form adicionar Referência para Pessoa

Porém eu não sei qual a melhor maneira ou a menos problemática para começar a *view*. Mas meu maior problema está na *controller*.

Lembrando que existe coisas básicas a ser levadas em conta como: *contato* só pode existir se existir a pessoa com id pra ele, o mesmo se dá a referência, e estes dois casos serão uma lista que pode incrementar-se... e como na *view* atribuir essa lista a *model*?

Na minha *action* como eu faria? Ou seja, quero saber como deveria ser passado essa *view* que acho que vai ficar complexa para a *action*. Teria que passar um FORM ou tem como passar o Objeto?

Comment: Está um pouco confusa a sua pergunta. Você pode reformular por gentileza?

Comment: @MatheusBessa reformulei

Answer (score 2):

No seu lugar, eu faria *Scaffold* da View *estática* mesmo. Tem um pacote NuGet que faz isso:

> Install-Package MvcScaffolding

Depois de ter a View estática eu faria ela em *Single Page*.

Para gerar seu Controller e suas Views, utilize o seguinte comando:

> scaffold controller Pessoa
>
> scaffold controller Conjuge
>
> scaffold controller Contato
>
> scaffold controller Referencia

Tendo os *Controllers* pré-moldados, o trabalho de confeccionar as *Views* fica mais simples.

Incremente uma pergunta para que eu possa incrementar minha resposta. Descreva o que você imagina para as suas *Views* (mestre-detalhe, Ajax, como se dará a transição entre as telas, etc.).

> Lembrando que existe coisas básicas a ser levadas em conta como: contato só pode existir se existir a pessoa com id pra ele, o mesmo se dá a referência, e estes dois casos serão uma lista que pode incrementar-se... e como na view atribuir essa lista a model?

Parece ser um caso típico de mestre-detalhe. Para este caso, há outro pacote NuGet que resolve seu problema: [MvcBeginCollectionItem](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).

> Na minha action como eu faria? Ou seja, quero saber como deveria ser passado essa view que acho que vai ficar complexa para a action. Teria que passar um FORM ou tem como passar o Objeto?

O ideal é sempre passar o objeto que instancia a classe do *Model*, que é a forma mais natural para o Entity Framework trabalhar.

Comment: Seria sim Mestre-Detalhe a Contato e Referencia