# Criar um gerador de formulário web

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Preciso criar um gerador de formulário web, ou seja criar o form, os campos, validações, CSS de modo que esta estrutura vá para um repositório de dados e ao consultar a estrutura monte
na tela o formulário.

Alguém tem ideia de qual tecnologia é melhor criar um projeto como esse?

Comment: Senbores, eu gostaria de fazer um gerador de formularios no estilo http://www.wufoo.com/ acho que não me expressei bem na minha pergunta inicial.

Answer (score 2):

Sim. Chama-se *Scaffolding*.

O Visual Studio possui *Scaffolding* embarcado a partir da versão 2013, e por linha de comando até a versão 2012 (mantido pela Microsoft) e 2013 e 2015 (mantido pela comunidade). Esse suporte por linha de comando pode ser instalado através do seguinte pacote NuGet:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding/ (para o Visual Studio 2012)
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding.VS2015/ (para os Visual Studio 2013 e 2015)
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/1.0.10 (apenas para o Visual Studio 2015, se a versão mais recente der algum erro)

Por linha de comando, ensino a usar os comandos nestas respostas:

- [Estrutura de Controller e View](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11151/estrutura-de-controller-e-view/11158#11158)
- [Mudar o padrão de nomenclatura das Views que são geradas pelo scaffold](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90536/mudar-o-padr%C3%A3o-de-nomenclatura-das-views-que-s%C3%A3o-geradas-pelo-scaffold/92294#92294)

### Usando o recurso embarcado do Visual Studio

Estou supondo que você está usando [Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) e [MVC5](http://asp.net/mvc/mvc5) no seu projeto.

Primeiro você precisa criar um *Model*. Vou colocar um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    public class Color
    {
        [Key]
        public int ColorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Code { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Depois clique com o botão direito no diretório *Controllers* da sua solução > <kbd>Add</kbd> > <kbd>Controller...</kbd>

[image: Add Controller]

Escolha a opção **MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework**:

[image: Add Scaffold]

Preencha o *Model* e a classe de contexto. Se ainda não existir uma classe de contexto, crie uma através do botão <kbd>+</kbd>. Clique em <kbd>Add</kbd>:

[image: Scaffolding 3]

Feito isso, Será criado um *Controller* com as operações básicas (Listar, Detalhar, Inserir, Editar e Excluir), mais ou menos como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: Views]

Comment: Cigano, eu gostaria de fazer um gerador de formularios no estilo http://www.wufoo.com/ entendeu? acho que não me expressei bem na minha pergunta inicial..

Comment: Ah, bom. Neste caso não apenas minha resposta não serve, como sua pergunta também merece ser fechada porque é ampla demais.