# Mudar o padrão de nomenclatura das Views que são geradas pelo scaffold

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, t4

Gostaria de mudar a nomenclatura em que o scaffold gera as Views:

**Padrão:**

```
Create.cshtml
Delete.cshtml
Details.cshtml
Edit.cshtml
Index.cshtml
```

**Quero que o scaffold crie dessa forma:**

```
Criar.cshtml
Excluir.cshtml
Exibir.cshtml
Editar.cshtml
Index.cshtml
```

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Só consegui sentar pra escrever isso agora.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para esta resposta, suponho que você está usando o pacote [MvcScaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/) na versão mais recente. Se você tiver algum problema com a versão mais recente, [use a versão 1.0.10, que funciona apenas para o VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/1.0.10). Não esqueça de fixar os números das versões para evitar atualizações indesejadas no seu `packages.config`:

```
<packages>
    <package id="MvcScaffolding.VS2015" version="1.0.10" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.0.10]" />
    <package id="T4Scaffolding.Core.VS2015" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.0.1]" />
    <package id="T4Scaffolding.VS2015" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net452" allowedVersions="[1.0.8]" />
</packages>
```

## Passo 1: Crie seu *CustomScaffold*

Eu criei o meu com o seguinte comando:

```
PM> scaffold CustomScaffolder Portugues
```

O Visual Studio irá criar no diretório `CodeTemplates` do seu projeto um outro diretório chamado `Scaffolders`, e dentro dele um diretório chamado `Portugues` com dois arquivos: um arquivo `.ps1` (extensão de script do PowerShell) e um arquivo `.cs.t4`, que não iremos utilizar. Fique à vontade para apagá-lo, se quiser.

## Passo 2: Alterando o *CustomScaffold*

Vá no `diretório do seu projeto\packages\MvcScaffolding.VS2015.<versão>\tools\Views`. Abra o arquivo `MvcScaffolding.Views.ps1`. Ele deve estar mais ou menos assim:

```
[T4Scaffolding.Scaffolder(Description = "Adds ASP.NET MVC views for Create/Read/Update/Delete/Index scenarios")][CmdletBinding()]
param(        
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)][string]$Controller,
    [string]$ModelType,
    [string]$Area,
    [alias("MasterPage")]$Layout = "",  # If not set, we'll use the default layout
    [alias("ContentPlaceholderIDs")][string[]]$SectionNames,
    [alias("PrimaryContentPlaceholderID")][string]$PrimarySectionName,
    [switch]$ReferenceScriptLibraries = $false,
    [string]$Project,
    [string]$CodeLanguage,
    [string[]]$TemplateFolders,
    [string]$ViewScaffolder = "View",
    [switch]$Force = $false
)

@("Create", "Edit", "Delete", "Details", "Index", "_CreateOrEdit") | %{
    Scaffold $ViewScaffolder -Controller $Controller -ViewName $_ -ModelType $ModelType -Template $_ -Area $Area -Layout $Layout -SectionNames $SectionNames -PrimarySectionName $PrimarySectionName -ReferenceScriptLibraries:$ReferenceScriptLibraries -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -OverrideTemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Force:$Force
}
```

O que vamos alterar é isso:

```
@("Create", "Edit", "Delete", "Details", "Index", "_CreateOrEdit") | %{
    Scaffold $ViewScaffolder -Controller $Controller -ViewName $_ -ModelType $ModelType -Template $_ -Area $Area -Layout $Layout -SectionNames $SectionNames -PrimarySectionName $PrimarySectionName -ReferenceScriptLibraries:$ReferenceScriptLibraries -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -OverrideTemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Force:$Force
}
```

Copie todo o conteúdo do arquivo `MvcScaffolding.Views.ps1` para o seu *CustomScaffold*. Altere o bloco acima para:

```
@("Criar", "Editar", "Excluir", "Detalhes", "Index", "_CriarOuEditar") | %{
    Scaffold $ViewScaffolder -Controller $Controller -ViewName $_ -ModelType $ModelType -Template $_ -Area $Area -Layout $Layout -SectionNames $SectionNames -PrimarySectionName $PrimarySectionName -ReferenceScriptLibraries:$ReferenceScriptLibraries -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -OverrideTemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Force:$Force
}
```

## Passo 3: Criando novos *CodeTemplates* em Português

Para o *Scaffold* não se perder, você vai precisar copiar os templates para o diretório do seu *CustomScaffold*.

Instalado o pacote, copie todos os arquivos de extensão `cs.t4` do diretório `diretório do seu projeto\MvcScaffolding.VS2015.<versão>\tools\RazorView` para o diretório do seu *CustomScaffold*. Feito isso, renomeie o nome dos arquivos para a convenção estabalecida no passo anterior. Os meus ficaram assim:

```
_CriarOuEditar.cs.t4
Criar.cs.t4
Detalhes.cs.t4
Editar.cs.t4
Empty.cs.t4
Excluir.cs.t4
Index.cs.t4
```

## Passo 4: Testes

Se você fez tudo certo, esse comando gera o *Scaffold* em português pra você:

```
PM> scaffold Portugues Teste2 -ModelType:MeuProjeto.Models.Banco
Added Criar view at 'Views\Teste2\Criar.cshtml'
Added Editar view at 'Views\Teste2\Editar.cshtml'
Added Excluir view at 'Views\Teste2\Excluir.cshtml'
Added Detalhes view at 'Views\Teste2\Detalhes.cshtml'
Added Index view at 'Views\Teste2\Index.cshtml'
```

## Considerações

Note que os *templates* do *Scaffolding* nativo não são compatíveis com os do MvcScaffolding, e que os *templates* do MvcScaffolding são um tanto quanto antigos, além de não serem feitos para o Bootstrap. Algum trabalho pode ser necessário para deixar os *templates* com uma carinha mais recente.

Adicionalmente, há o agravante de estes *templates* não terem o suporte a `async`, mas nada o impede de implementar todos os métodos como `async` se assim desejar.

---

### Mas, e se eu quiser customizar o processo inteiro de geração de *Controller* com *Views*?

Bom, aí você terá que praticamente copiar um *Scaffolder* do MvcScaffolding e alterá-lo para gerar tudo em português.

### Eu vou ter que gerar isso?

Não. Estou de bom humor e fiz isso pra vocês:

#### `CodeTemplates/Scaffolders/Portugues/Portugues.ps1`

```
[T4Scaffolding.ControllerScaffolder("Controller with read/write action and views, using EF data access code", Description = "Adds an ASP.NET MVC controller with views and data access code", SupportsModelType = $true, SupportsDataContextType = $true, SupportsViewScaffolder = $true)][CmdletBinding()]
param(     
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][string]$ControllerName,   
    [string]$ModelType,
    [string]$Project,
    [string]$CodeLanguage,
    [string]$DbContextType,
    [string]$Area,
    [string]$ViewScaffolder = "View",
    [alias("MasterPage")]$Layout,
    [alias("ContentPlaceholderIDs")][string[]]$SectionNames,
    [alias("PrimaryContentPlaceholderID")][string]$PrimarySectionName,
    [switch]$ReferenceScriptLibraries = $false,
    [switch]$Repository = $false,
    [switch]$NoChildItems = $false,
    [string[]]$TemplateFolders,
    [switch]$Force = $false,
    [string]$ForceMode
)

# Interpret the "Force" and "ForceMode" options
$overwriteController = $Force -and ((!$ForceMode) -or ($ForceMode -eq "ControllerOnly"))
$overwriteFilesExceptController = $Force -and ((!$ForceMode) -or ($ForceMode -eq "PreserveController"))

# If you haven't specified a model type, we'll guess from the controller name
if (!$ModelType) {
    if ($ControllerName.EndsWith("Controller", [StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        # If you've given "PeopleController" as the full controller name, we're looking for a model called People or Person
        $ModelType = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($ControllerName, "Controller$", "", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
        $foundModelType = Get-ProjectType $ModelType -Project $Project -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if (!$foundModelType) {
            $ModelType = [string](Get-SingularizedWord $ModelType)
            $foundModelType = Get-ProjectType $ModelType -Project $Project -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    } else {
        # If you've given "people" as the controller name, we're looking for a model called People or Person, and the controller will be PeopleController
        $ModelType = $ControllerName
        $foundModelType = Get-ProjectType $ModelType -Project $Project -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if (!$foundModelType) {
            $ModelType = [string](Get-SingularizedWord $ModelType)
            $foundModelType = Get-ProjectType $ModelType -Project $Project -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        if ($foundModelType) {
            $ControllerName = [string](Get-PluralizedWord $foundModelType.Name) + "Controller"
        }
    }
    if (!$foundModelType) { throw "Cannot find a model type corresponding to a controller called '$ControllerName'. Try supplying a -ModelType parameter value." }
} else {
    # If you have specified a model type
    $foundModelType = Get-ProjectType $ModelType -Project $Project
    if (!$foundModelType) { return }
    if (!$ControllerName.EndsWith("Controller", [StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        $ControllerName = $ControllerName + "Controller"
    }
}
Write-Host "Scaffolding $ControllerName..."

if(!$DbContextType) { $DbContextType = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace((Get-Project $Project).Name, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "") + "Context" }
if (!$NoChildItems) {
    if ($Repository) {
        Scaffold Repository -ModelType $foundModelType.FullName -DbContextType $DbContextType -Area $Area -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$overwriteFilesExceptController
    } else {
        $dbContextScaffolderResult = Scaffold DbContext -ModelType $foundModelType.FullName -DbContextType $DbContextType -Area $Area -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage
        $foundDbContextType = $dbContextScaffolderResult.DbContextType
        if (!$foundDbContextType) { return }
    }
}
if (!$foundDbContextType) { $foundDbContextType = Get-ProjectType $DbContextType -Project $Project }
if (!$foundDbContextType) { return }

$primaryKey = Get-PrimaryKey $foundModelType.FullName -Project $Project -ErrorIfNotFound
if (!$primaryKey) { return }

$outputPath = Join-Path Controllers $ControllerName
# We don't create areas here, so just ensure that if you specify one, it already exists
if ($Area) {
    $areaPath = Join-Path Areas $Area
    if (-not (Get-ProjectItem $areaPath -Project $Project)) {
        Write-Error "Cannot find area '$Area'. Make sure it exists already."
        return
    }
    $outputPath = Join-Path $areaPath $outputPath
}

# Prepare all the parameter values to pass to the template, then invoke the template with those values
$repositoryName = $foundModelType.Name + "Repository"
$defaultNamespace = (Get-Project $Project).Properties.Item("DefaultNamespace").Value
$modelTypeNamespace = [T4Scaffolding.Namespaces]::GetNamespace($foundModelType.FullName)
$controllerNamespace = [T4Scaffolding.Namespaces]::Normalize($defaultNamespace + "." + [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($outputPath).Replace([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar, "."))
$areaNamespace = if ($Area) { [T4Scaffolding.Namespaces]::Normalize($defaultNamespace + ".Areas.$Area") } else { $defaultNamespace }
$dbContextNamespace = $foundDbContextType.Namespace.FullName
$repositoriesNamespace = [T4Scaffolding.Namespaces]::Normalize($areaNamespace + ".Models")
$modelTypePluralized = Get-PluralizedWord $foundModelType.Name
$relatedEntities = [Array](Get-RelatedEntities $foundModelType.FullName -Project $project)
if (!$relatedEntities) { $relatedEntities = @() }

$templateName = if($Repository) { "ControllerWithRepository" } else { "ControllerWithContext" }
Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $outputPath -Template $templateName -Model @{
    ControllerName = $ControllerName;
    ModelType = [MarshalByRefObject]$foundModelType; 
    PrimaryKey = [string]$primaryKey; 
    DefaultNamespace = $defaultNamespace; 
    AreaNamespace = $areaNamespace; 
    DbContextNamespace = $dbContextNamespace;
    RepositoriesNamespace = $repositoriesNamespace;
    ModelTypeNamespace = $modelTypeNamespace; 
    ControllerNamespace = $controllerNamespace; 
    DbContextType = [MarshalByRefObject]$foundDbContextType;
    Repository = $repositoryName; 
    ModelTypePluralized = [string]$modelTypePluralized; 
    RelatedEntities = $relatedEntities;
} -SuccessMessage "Added controller {0}" -TemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$overwriteController

if (!$NoChildItems) {
    $controllerNameWithoutSuffix = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($ControllerName, "Controller$", "", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
    if ($ViewScaffolder) {
        @("Criar", "Editar", "Excluir", "Detalhes", "Indice", "_CriarOuEditar") | %{
            Scaffold $ViewScaffolder -Controller $controllerNameWithoutSuffix -ViewName $_ -ModelType $foundModelType.FullName -Template $_ -Area $Area -Layout $Layout -SectionNames $SectionNames -PrimarySectionName $PrimarySectionName -ReferenceScriptLibraries:$ReferenceScriptLibraries -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -OverrideTemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Force:$overwriteFilesExceptController
        }
    }
}
```

Certifique-se de que todos estes arquivos estão no mesmo diretório do arquivo `Portugues.ps1`:

[image: Arquivos do Scaffolding em Português]

---

### Posso usar o MvcScaffolding juntamente com o *Scaffolding* nativo?

Pode, mas note que serão gerados dois contextos: Um `ApplicationDbContext` e `SeuProjetoContext`. Para evitar duplicidade de contextos, apague `SeuProjetoContext` e renomeie `ApplicationDbContext` para `SeuProjetoContext`.