# Configurar Scaffold para gerar classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, t4

Tem como configurar o Scaffold para gerar outras classes além do padrão(Controllers e Views) ?

Comment: Da pra gerar as classes a partir de um banco de dados já pronto. É isso? Se não, quais classes você quer gerar?

Comment: Não, quero configurar Scaffold para gerar classes que eu configura como ex.: ClienteViewModel que será baseada na model Cliente. Sei que Scaffold usa reflection então pensei na possibilidade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim.

Primeiro você precisa gerar um *template* para seus *ViewModels*. [Há um pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc5CodeTemplatesCSharp/) que tem vários *templates* como exemplo.

Feito isso, modifique um template de *View* (salve com outro nome) e coloque em código tudo o que gostaria de ter no seu *ViewModel*. Não esqueça de mudar o *output extension* de:

```
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>
```

Para:

```
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
```

Para executar seu *Scaffold*, clique com o botão direito no diretório de *ViewModels* > Add > New Scaffolded Item... .

Na próxima tela, escolha Common > MVC > View.

> Veja que esse passo é um chuncho, justamente porque o pacote que eu ia usar estava com bug na data desta resposta, mas vou manter essa parte para didática e fins históricos.

Na tela de *Add View*, campo **Template**, escolha o seu *template* de *ViewModel*. Coloque a **Model Class** como o *Model* a ser usado como base e clique em Ok.

Se tudo correr bem, o *Scaffold* de seu *ViewModel* deve ocorrer sem problemas.

---

## O passo correto, sem chuncho

A maneira elegante de fazer a mesma coisa é [usando o pacote MvcScaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/).

Para *Views*, [use a descrição desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92294/2999).

Para *Controllers*, o princípio é o mesmo, mas você irá copiar o script do *Scaffold* que está em `packages\MvcScaffolding.VS2015.<versão>\tools\Controller\MvcScaffolding.Controller.ps1` e fazer as devidas modificações.

Se precisar de ajuda para as modificações, é só falar.

Comment: Vou testar. Não teria como o scaffold que usamos para gerar as controllers, que no caso já gera as views, fazer isso? Valeu!

Comment: Eu acho o das Controllers mais limitado, mas pode ser também. Fique no aguardo de uma atualização dessa resposta nos próximos dias. [O David vai atualizar o pacote dele](https://github.com/processedbeets/ASP.NET-MVC-Scaffolding/issues/1), aí melhoro isso.

Comment: Cigano, pode me ajudar com isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90536/mudar-o-padr%C3%A3o-de-nomenclatura-das-views-que-s%C3%A3o-geradas-pelo-scaffold

Comment: Atualizei aqui também.