# Como fazer Scaffolding em ASP.Net MVC com textos e recursos em pt-BR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, template, português-do-brasil, scaffold

Como fazer os textos gerados pelo *Scaffolding* do ASP.Net MVC serem textos em pt-BR?

Obs.: Não é utilizar recursos do ASP.NET MVC pt-BR. Os recursos apenas traduzem mensagens geradas automaticamente, e não fazem parte do *Scaffolding*.

Comment: @diegofm a outra pergunta foi eu mesmo que fiz, e não é duplicada, uma se trata de scaffolding e outra de recursos gerados automaticamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vou precisar desta resposta para continuar o gancho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17594/internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usando-asp-net-mvc/17600#17600).

Considerando que você fez tudo o que estava na resposta do link, vamos configurar um *Model*:

```
public class CustomUser
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CustomUserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FirstNameIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "LastName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameIsRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Points", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "PointsOutsideRange", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    public int Points { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Suspended", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public Boolean Suspended { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Esta é a parte mais importante das traduções, porque aqui que vão as mensagens de erro. `ErrorMessageResourceName` ou `Name` nos atributos de exemplo são as colunas índice de cada arquivo de *Resource*. `ResourceType` indica qual o tipo do *Resource* estamos nos referindo.

Você não precisa usar o mesmo arquivo de *Resource* para tudo. Neste caso, acho legal fazer um para os campos do *Model* e outro para as mensagens de validação.

Feito isso, vamos finalmente falar do *Scaffolding*.

Separei algumas respostas em que falo disso:

- [O que é scaffold?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119731/o-que-%C3%A9-scaffold/119751#119751)
- [Estrutura de Controller e View](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11151/estrutura-de-controller-e-view/11158#11158)
- [Mudar o padrão de nomenclatura das Views que são geradas pelo scaffold](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90536/mudar-o-padr%C3%A3o-de-nomenclatura-das-views-que-s%C3%A3o-geradas-pelo-scaffold/92294#92294)
- [Criar um gerador de formulário web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32748/criar-um-gerador-de-formul%C3%A1rio-web/32749#32749)

Assim sendo, sabemos que os arquivos de *templates* estão nos seguintes diretórios:

- `diretório do seu projeto\packages\MvcScaffolding.VS2015.<versão>\tools\Views` para o MvcScaffolding. Copie os diretórios de lá para dentro do seu projeto, diretório `CodeTemplates/Scaffolders` e os renomeie da seguinte forma:

  - `Action -> MvcScaffolding.Action`
  - `ActionUnitTest -> MvcScaffolding.ActionUnitTest`
  - `ActionWithUnitTest -> MvcScaffolding.ActionWithUnitTest`
  - `AspxView -> MvcScaffolding.AspxView`
  - `Controller -> MvcScaffolding.Controller`
  - `RazorView -> MvcScaffolding.RazorView`
  - `Views -> MvcScaffolding.Views`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates`. Copie todos os diretórios para a raiz do seu diretório `CodeTemplates` do projeto.

Se `CodeTemplates` e `Scaffolders` dentro dele não existem, crie-os.

Você precisará instalar [esta ferramenta aqui para poder editar os *templates*](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/784cf592-b797-4d4d-ad33-331fcf63faad). São templates T4 que podem ser editados livremente por você.

Comece pelos diretórios `RazorView` e `MvcView`, respectivamente. É nele que ficam as *Views*.

Assim sendo, você pode simplesmente traduzir as mensagens ou então criar *Resources* e usá-los também para as *Views*.

Se não faltou nada, eu acho que é isso.